# Android OnClickListener collided?

Tags: android, onclick

Sorry for weird question, I am still Newbie for Android programming.

I have following code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

And eclipse telling me the `View.OnClickListener` has collided with another import statement.

I am using `Dialog.OnClickListener` for my `AlertDialog` and `View.OnClickListener` for my `Button`. I am use this `Button` to showing the `AlertDialog`. How to do the good and right way for this?

Here's my code:

```
// This OnClickListener is still showing error in eclipse    
btnListLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showAllListLocation(location);
    }
});

private void showAllListLocation(String[] location) {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);
    b.setTitle("Choose your location");
    b.setSingleChoiceItems(location, 0, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    b.show();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code where you define the `OnClickListener` for each. You may just have to fully qualify them.

Comment: @Squonk : what's the point of importing if you end up fully qualifying ?

Comment: @njzk2 : By fully qualifying I mean, for example, using `new View.OnClickListener()` instead of just `new OnClickListener()`. That's why I asked the OP for more code because it isn't clear how he/she is trying to implement the listeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Button** extends **View**. So for **Button** you can use **View.OnClickListener**

For Dialogs - **DialogInterface.OnClickListener**

## Simple use:

```
Button b;
//b init

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(_context_)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setTitle("MyDialog")
    .setMessage("MyMessage")
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int which) 
            {
                //Logic
            }
        }).show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `import`, you can explicitly declare the type of `OnClickListener()` to avoid the collision:

```
Button a = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            a.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("abc", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Many class has a click listeners to handle click events.

You are importing 2 classes, so compiler doesn't know which will be used since you call `onClick()`. It warns you.

If you want to override `onClick()` function for Button, you must use `View.OnClickListener`.

For button:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
                // Here is where button click runs.
        }

});
```